# How to correctly make mock methods call original virtual method

Tags: c++, googlemock

I want to define for a mocked method the behavior that when it is called in a test, all the `EXPECTED_CALL` and `ON_CALL` specific for that test are being checked, but still the original method is being executed after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the delegating-to-real technique, as per [Google Mock documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#delegating-calls-to-a-real-object):

> You can use the delegating-to-real technique to ensure that your mock has the same behavior as the real object while retaining the ability to validate calls. Here's an example:

```
using ::testing::_;
using ::testing::AtLeast;
using ::testing::Invoke;

class MockFoo : public Foo {
 public:
  MockFoo() {
    // By default, all calls are delegated to the real object.
    ON_CALL(*this, DoThis())
        .WillByDefault(Invoke(&real_, &Foo::DoThis));
    ON_CALL(*this, DoThat(_))
        .WillByDefault(Invoke(&real_, &Foo::DoThat));
    ...
  }
  MOCK_METHOD0(DoThis, ...);
  MOCK_METHOD1(DoThat, ...);
  ...
 private:
  Foo real_;
};
...

  MockFoo mock;

  EXPECT_CALL(mock, DoThis())
      .Times(3);
  EXPECT_CALL(mock, DoThat("Hi"))
      .Times(AtLeast(1));
  ... use mock in test ...
```