# Unable to inject mocked object in another mocked class

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have 3 classes A, B, C
I have another class called RefObj

```
class RefObj{
   virtual void func(params){// do}
}

class B {
   B(A* a_obj) : _a_obj(a_obj)
   
   void test(){
   // other code here
      _a_obj->get_ref_object()->func(params);
   }
   private:
     A* _a_obj;
}
  
class A {
   A() {
     RefObj* refobj = new RefObj(_function);
     B b_obj = std::unique_ptr<B>(new B(this));
     C c_obj = std::unique_ptr<B>(new C(refobj));
   }
   RefObj* get_ref_object() {
      return refobj;
   }
}
```

I am writing test case for class B. I need to test calls to `func()` in RefObj class. I am having issues with creating mocks.
I tried creating mock object for class A but not sure how to inject mock for RefObj

I have tried something like

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

class RefObjMock: public RefObj
{
public:
  RefObjMock();
  MOCK_METHOD0(func, void());
}

class AMock: public A
{
public:
  AMock();
  MOCK_METHOD0(get_ref_object, RefObjMock*());

private:
  RefObjMock* _ref_obj;
}
```

But I get error on the mocked function get_ref_object
Basically I cannot make it return the `_ref_obj` and it returns null

Any help would be really appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why does `B` need to know about `RefObj`? Why can't `A` provide functionality that calls `RefObj::test()` internally, without exposing `RefObj`?

Comment: So I have abstracted other functions but B's test function does other things and then needs to call func() in the end

Comment: What is code under test? I do not see `virtual` keyword xor templates, so there is no dynamic or static polymorphism, so how mocks can be injected? You need any kind of polymorphism to be able to inject dependency.

Comment: Please provide [mcve] you can start from this [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/76nPrxEzo).

Comment: My point is that you have an architecture problem that makes your code harder to test. We could provide you with code that would make it work, but that won't solve the issue with your architecture. If you can break the dependency chain in `B::test()` and replace it with `_a_obj->some_func_that_uses_ref_obj_internally();`, your problem with mocking will be gone.

Comment: @MarekR sorry my bad the func() is virtual, I have updated the qn

Comment: @Yksisarvinen
I thought of doing something like this in class

`void func1(){ _ref_obj->func(params)}` But it felt like it will be performance impacting to have multiple function call stacks

Comment: Again: What is code under test and how this code accepts dependency? I do not see proper use of polymorphism - just adding `virtual` doesn't fix this issue. Please provide [mcve]!

Comment: What if you just simply don't mock that method?

Comment: Or you can do it this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46821108/3738870

Comment: Re "performance impacting to have multiple function call stacks": A function body of just `{ _ref_obj->func(params); }` where both functions have return type `void` is possibly a candidate for a Tail Call Optimization. (But not if the statement involves temporary objects of classes with non-trivial destructors.)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
struct params {
    int a;
    int b;
};

class RefObj {
public:
    virtual ~RefObj() = default;
    virtual void func(params) = 0;
};

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual RefObj* get_ref_object() = 0;
};

class B {
public:
    B(A* a_obj)
                : _a_obj(a_obj) {
    }

    void test() {
        // other code here
        params p{42, 314};
        _a_obj->get_ref_object()->func(p);
    }

private:
    A* _a_obj;
};

class RefObjMock : public RefObj {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(func, void(params));
};

class AMock : public A {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(get_ref_object, RefObjMock*());
};

auto MatchParams(params expected) {
    return testing::AllOf(testing::Field(&params::a, expected.a), testing::Field(&params::b, expected.b));
}

TEST(BTest, Test_test) {
    AMock a_mock{};
    RefObjMock ref_obj_mock{};

    B object_under_test{&a_mock};

    params expexted_param{42, 314};

    EXPECT_CALL(a_mock, get_ref_object()).WillRepeatedly(testing::Return(&ref_obj_mock));
    EXPECT_CALL(ref_obj_mock, func(MatchParams(expexted_param)));

    object_under_test.test();
}
```

Most important changes:

- usage of pure virtual base classes for dependency injection.
- removal of unnecessary default ctors.
- addition of virtual dtors.
- matcher for `params`.
- simple test for `class B` using `class A` and `RefObj` and their mocks.